# Как можно реализовать кнопку удаления записи через Ajax?

Tags: ajax, javascript, php

Привет. 
Разбираюсь с ajax. Подскажите, как можно реализовать кнопку удаления записи. Ничего в голову не идет.

Index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function showList(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "task.php",
        data: "",
        success: function(response){
            $('#response').html(response);
        }
    });
};
function addTask(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "task.php",
        data: "f=add",
        success: function(response){
            $('#response').html(response);
        }
    });
};
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="response"></div>
<button onclick="addTask();">Добавить</button>
</body>
</html>
```

task.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<?
$conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
mysql_select_db("task", $conn);
$q = "select * from list";
$r = mysql_query($q);
echo "Сейчас дел: ".mysql_num_rows($r);
$command = $_POST['f'];
echo "<TABLE border='1'>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($r, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    echo "<TR>";
    echo "<TD>$row[ID]</TD>";
    echo "<TD>$row[Name]</TD>";
    echo "<TD>$row[Desc]</TD>";
    echo "</TR>"; }
echo "</TABLE>";
    if( $command == "add" )
    {
        echo 'Дело добавленно!';
        $r = mysql_query("INSERT INTO list (name) VALUES ('тут текст')");
    }
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @VINET, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Привет.

Я бы советовал отправлять такие запросы, с помощью `$.post()`:

```
$.post('твой url', params, function(){ //params - объект параметров
        window.location.href = ''; // обновим страницу
});
```

А вообще я обычно делаю гораздо проще:

```
$.post('твой url' + $(this).data('id'), function(){ // id записи как параметр функции
        window.location.href = ''; // обновим страницу
});
```

А у себя в php принимай, как обычные POST данные.

Если всё-таки горит через ajax, то в параметре data передай объект параметров.

**P.S.** Может, уже пора юзать ООП в php? **И.. Отступы.. Отступы.. Отступы..**